# T-SQL remove duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which shows which Football team played which football team, the table example:

```
[ TeamId1 | TeamId2 ]
[ 1       | 2       ]
[ 1       | 3       ]
[ 3       | 1       ]
[ 3       | 2       ]
```

I need a query to omit the duplicates, however this is considered a duplicate:

```
Row 1:    
TeamId1: 4     
TeamId2: 3  

Row 2:
TeamId1: 3  
TeamId2: 4
```

In this case I would just like to return Row 1, however there are some rows in which there is NOT a duplicate.

**EDIT**

Hopefully my question and table example are better now.

Comment: First according to what criteria? What does the table and data look like, what results do you expect? You could easily add `WHERE TeamID1>=TeamID2` for example, if you are certain you'll always have a result similar to `Row 1`

Comment: I have now improved the question. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have at most one row per pair:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
WHERE team1 < team2
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*
FROM t
WHERE team2 > team1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t t2
                  WHERE t2.team1 = t.team2 AND
                        t2.team2 = t.team1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work for you?
Always consider the highest as Team1 and the lowest as Team2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE Team1 > Team2 THEN Team1
    ELSE Team2 END AS Team1, 
    CASE Team1 < Team2 THEN Team1 
    ELSE Team2 END AS Team2
FROM <yourTable>
```

Comment: This won't remove the duplicates. This could go in the CTE or subquery that would normalize results, allowing a simple 'DISTINCT' to eliminate the duplicates

Comment: Are you sure? I've put a distinict keyword at the beginnig, would not that remove the duplicates?

Comment: Oops, didn't notice it. If the OP only wanted to return the IDs, this would work although it wouldn't be the fastest solution. I suspect the OP's homework asks for the entire row though and the `no CTE` clause is meant to prevent swapping aroung the TeamIDs

Answer (score 0):

The general pseudocode for this is where the team ID's are not repeated in opposite order, with the `T2.TeamId1`  greater than `T1.TeamId1`:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (TeamId1 int, TeamId2 int)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1,2), (1,3), (3,1), (3,2), (4,3), (3,4)

SELECT *
  FROM @temp T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM @temp T2 
                    WHERE T2.TeamId2 = T1.TeamId1 
                      AND T2.TeamId1 = T1.TeamId2
                      AND T2.TeamId1 > T1.TeamId1)
```

Produces output:

```
TeamId1 TeamId2
1       2
3       1
3       2
4       3
```

---

The above query could also be interpreted as a left join, filtering where a T2 field is NULL by the left join condition:

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM @temp T1 LEFT JOIN @temp T2 ON T2.TeamId2 = T1.TeamId1 
                                  AND T2.TeamId1 = T1.TeamId2
                                  AND T2.TeamId1 > T1.TeamId1
 WHERE T2.TeamId1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

see if this works :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                    WHEN TeamId1 > TeamId2 THEN TeamId2
                    ELSE TeamId1
                END TeamId1,
                CASE
                    WHEN TeamId1 > TeamId2 THEN TeamId1
                    ELSE TeamId2
                END TeamId2
FROM foot_ballteam
```